# Regex Match Repeated Occurrences of the Same Character Chosen from a Set

Tags: regex

I have been writing patterns to find common acronyms and am running into situations where it would be handy match occurrences of the same character where the given character is selected from a set of candidates.

For example, let's say we want to match all variants of the Free Software Foundation, ie. FSF.  We want to match F.S.F. or FSF or F S F or possibly messy versions F.SF and maybe cases where the . is replaced by the / ie. F/S/F.  Which looks like this:

```
\bF[\.\/ ]?S[\.\/ ]?F[\.\/]?(?!\S)
```

However, we probably don't want to match F.S/F.  So we would like the separator to to be consistent in the same match (. or / or ).  Is there a way to this without using alternations?

```
\b(F[\.]?S[\.]?F[\.]?|F[\/]?S[\/]?F[\/]?|F[ ]?S[ ]?F)(?!\S)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\bF([^a-zA-Z0-9])?S\1?F\1?\b
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/tX2bH4/45

The second separator will be same as the first one as it is being captured at first and being referenced by using `\1`.

NOTE to match a trailing separator use:

```
(?:\bF([^a-zA-Z0-9])S\1F\1?)|(?:\bFSF\b)
```

Comment: Pretty nice! I am kicking myself for not thinking of that.  Can you get it to match F.S.F. with the trailing period?

Comment: You leveled up my regex usage.  First time I needed a match operator in an expression. Thanks!

Comment: I am looking for substrings so I am using ``\b`` and ``(?!\S)``.